Etymology of 交番
What is the etymology of 交番 (police box / small neighborhood police station)? I don't understand how 交 (mingle / mixing) and 番 (number in a series / turn) combine to mean police box / small neighborhood police station.

What have you been able to find in trying to research the answer yourself?

@Leebo Both wiktionary and Gogen Yurai didn't have entries for 交番. I also asked chat-gpt and got this: "The term 交番 originally referred to a practice where police officers would alternate shifts at a specific post or location to ensure continuous monitoring and safety. This system of alternating duties is captured in the word 交番, where officers took turns ("交") on watch ("番")." But I'm not sure how accurate / trustworthy this is. If you have any other good resources for compound etymology, I'd love to know ;).

Wiktionary does mention 交替して番をすること https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%A4%E7%95%AA

@Leebo I was looking at the english one. And isn't that just a definition? But I'm assuming you mean that police box 交番 comes from taking turns to keep watch?

You were asking how the two kanji used in 交番 relate to each other right? The definition expresses that.

@Pheonix 番をする. Apparently only in Japanese, 番 means "turn to keep watch", so 交番 means to "switch turn to keep watch".

If you look up 交番 in 旺文社国語辞典, you will find

こう‐ばん【交番】カウ――
① （もと「交番所（こうばんしよ）」の略）警察官の詰め所。派出所。
⇒駐在所
...
①は、一八七四（明治七）年、東京警視庁管内に設けられたのが最初。当初は、警察官が交替で立ち番をする活動地点をさした。

交番 used to refer to the place where police take turns (交替) to stand on guard (立ち番).

So 番 (number in a series / turn) is used to represent the different turns of standing guard? And how does 交 (mingle / mixing) relate to taking turns (交替)?

@Pheonix Don't just stick to one or two dictionary translations. Check the full range of meanings there is. 交 can also mean "to hand over", "to intersect" or "to exchange".  Also check the possible verbs spelt with this kanji, such as 交わす, 交ざる, 交ぜる and 交える. Look it up in Chinese dictionaries may help too. In this case, "to exchange" would fit.

@Vun-HughVaw I don't see any of those definitions in the dictionary I usually use https://jotoba.de/search/1/%E4%BA%A4?l=en-US. Do you have any recommendations for more thorough dictionaries / Chinese dictionaries? I recently came across this one: https://www.chinese-characters.org/meaning/4/4EA4.html but it seems a bit outdated and unsafe. Also, how do those definitions of "to hand over", "to intersect" and "to exchange" become "to stand on guard"?

@Pheonix the jotoba page you linked includes many kun'yomi readings for 交. Kun'yomi readings come primarily from the meaning of the kanji expressed with Japanese-origin words. Kun'yomi effectively means "meaning reading."

@Pheonix I use yellowbridge.com for the English translations of Chinese words in a pinch, but honestly all free Japanese-English and Chinese-English inevitably fall short. Translations for kanji are supposed to be "glosses", which mean they're very brief and nuanceless, and helpful mostly to linguists rather than laymen. For individual kanji, looking up Chinese entries on Wiktionary often helps.

@Pheonix 'Also, how do those definitions of "to hand over", "to intersect" and "to exchange" become "to stand on guard"?' They don't. It's specifically the compound 交番 that does. The sense development might have been something like this: 交番 "to switch turn on guard" (番 means "turn" but also specifically "watch/guard/vigil", a sense seemingly unique to Japanese) > 交番所 "guard station" > 交番 "guard station" (shortened).

@Vun-HughVaw Alright thanks, I think this makes a bit more sense. On a similar note, what exactly is a 交番 (police box / small neighborhood police station) and how is it different from a normal police station, as this seems to be an exclusively Japanese thing?

交番, according to the 精選版 日本国語大辞典 (at kotobank.jp), is a noun/suru-verb for "to switch turn" (obvious enough, right?), but also specifically short for 交番所. For the rest, see Jimmy Yang's answer.
Edit: I think I know why the asker struggled to figure out this word. 番 could be any kind of "turn", but also specifically "turn on guard". Imagine watchmen take turn watching. Imagine it like night "shifts" or something. The word 番人 for example means "watchman". The verb phrase 番をする means "to keep watch". For more examples and translations, see the Kenkyusha's New Japanese-English Dictionary.
Basically, 交番 means "to switch/exchange turn to be on watch".
